# The baby is crying all the time or has been crying all the time?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

> Where are you? the baby has been crying all the time.

or

> Where are you? the baby is crying all the time.

which one is correct?

and also, is it correct to say:

> Babies are crying all the time; I do not know why.

or should it be in Present Simple because it is a fact?

Sorry, the Grammar is badly delivered to students in my university. It is just driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither seems ungrammatical to me, though I would vastly favor the first sentence over the second. The phrase *all the time* makes this a little bit harder, as it has a literal interpretation (at all possible times) and a colloquial interpretation (very often).

The first sentence, with *has been crying all the time*, suggests that the baby was crying in the (recent, from context) past and is still doing so in the present. The context of the sentence suggests to me that the crying is not the typical state for the baby, and that there is a presumption that the listener/reader will do something to address the crying.

The second sentence gives the impression that crying all the time is a typical behavior for this particular baby. *Is crying* indicates crying at the present moment, and including *all the time* in the same sentence suggests that the baby is always crying at the present moment. Which is to say, the baby is *always* crying. In this case, the *Where are you?* question seems less meaningful to me. If the baby constantly cries, what good would my presence be? Would it really be so surprising that I would be **anywhere** other than where the crying baby is? This sentence suggests to me that there is information I'm not getting from the text as written, in which case the sentence itself could probably be changed and improved.

Your final sentence is correct in that it can be parsed appropriately, but whether or not it is better than another depends on what you'd like to express. *Babies are crying all the time* would mean that some group of babies (possibly all babies anywhere, ever) are crying constantly (or frequently, as with the colloquial interpretation of *all the time*). *Babies cry all the time* would be understood as "frequent crying is a typical behavior of babies", and carries no suggestion that babies are in the middle of crying at all possible moments.

Answer (score 0):

I would say "Where were you" if the person just returned; or "Where are you if this is on the phone.  (It would be gentler if you omit "all the time.")
Babies cry all the time.